# Control that changes state automatically and needs to be a part of a form. Any ideas?

Tags: forms, gui-design, controls, checkboxes, settings

I need an example of a control that changes its state automatically once a condition has been satisfied.

I need to use such a control to allow admins to set a flag at the user level that would ask that user to change password at the time of next login. Most of the examples that I came across use wither a toggle or a checkbox. While they seem to do that job I don't think they communicate that their state would change automatically once the user changes their password. 
Since all the rest of the values on the page would be retained till changed explicitly by the admin it makes sense that this control that works differently is visually different from the rest.

[image: example of a checkbox]

[image: another one using a checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

You can create two state control, one for the time before the request to change password was issued (or after it had changed), and second is upon the selection of the option and while request is pending. Animating the transition will be nice and make it even more clear.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi1T19.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this issue but I feel uncomfortable in changing the state of the checkbox in the manner you have shown. Apart from being inconsistent interaction it also does not let the user unselect should they want to go back on the previous state.

Comment: I think the keyword "next" here is the most important. Perhaps, instead of changing the control to reflect that you clicked the option, show some sort of note behind the option when the user has changed their password? This wouldn't change the behaviour of a known control, but show the user why the option has changed by itself.

Comment: @Ramjera, you can add 'Cancel' control at the end of the text to solve the 'go back to previous state' issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be 2 ways of handling it.

### Option 1. Word the permission in such as way that it would not need to change state.

e.g.

[ ] User must change password after a password reset

### Option 2. Tie the checkbox directly to the one-time action so it's obvious that it will only affect this specific instance

e.g.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdwuZf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I like your second option. We have decided to actually separate this flag and pull it out of the form to ensure that users do not expect to save the state of this flag.